# Mutually exclusive pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that pairs user up based on a criteria. The query will return a dynamic amount of rows, equal to the amount of pairs that fit the criteria. The query returns two fields, `id1` and `id2`, each being an id of a user. How would I create the query so that the ids don't show up again in another row?

Example of what I want returned:

```
id1 id2
001 003
004 006
009 011
023 042
```

Example of what I **don't** want returned:

```
id1 id2
001 003
003 004
012 002
023 012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some table, say `Users`, and you want to pair users.  You might also have a `where` clause or other criteria.

You can actually do this.  Enumerate the rows and then do a conditional aggregation based on combining adjacent even and odd values:

```
select min(u.userid) as userid1, max(u.userid) as userid2
from (select u.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from users u cross join 
           (select @rn := 0) vars
     ) u
group by floor((seqnum - 1) / 2)
having userid1 <> userid2;
```

You can easily add a `where` clause in the subquery.

Comment: Using that query, it simply outputs every user's id in both fields. I'm going to assume you mean `group by floor((seqnum-1)/2)`, which does combine even/odd but, in my case, returns the last user twice as a pair of itself ex. id1: 199 id2: also 199. I've remedied this by appending `having id2>id1`, and it seems to be working. I need to test it with criteria now.